# How to change color of a layer in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, color

http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/ol_simple.html

this is my website for test.

I add two layers in openlayers.

And I want to change color in one of two layers.

```
var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({fill: true,fillColor: "#ff0000"});
var BounderyshpLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3826'),style: myStyle});
```

[image]

why is it not work!?

Comment: You should remove the extra comma after sm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this:

```
var myStyle= {fillColor: "#ff0000"};

             var BounderyshpLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
             projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3826'),
             style: myStyle
             });
```

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/2xvfbtdw/

or even use a stylemap with different style for default and select:

```
var defStyle = {fillColor: "#ff0000",strokeColor: "green", strokeOpacity: "0.7", strokeWidth: 3, cursor: "pointer"};
        var sty = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(defStyle, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);

        var sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': sty,
            'select': {strokeColor: "red", fillColor: "green"}
        });

        var BounderyshpLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector({
             projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3826'),
             styleMap: sm,
             });
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/yxr5wdjo/

nice website with Information about the Feature-Style and Stylemap:
http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olstyle.html

PS: Just for demonstration purposes: If you open your website and use the console of your debug-tool (firebug for example) you run this code in your developer tools (non permanent change of course):

```
map.layers[2].style={fillColor: "#ff0000",fillOpacity:"0.5"};map.layers[2].redraw();
```

have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I tried your method. But it is not working, too.Can you help me again!?

Comment: can your post you last try here to see whats wrong? I just update my answer with something that you can also try...